# Fetch target entries that have been linked through an Entries field

Tags: relatedto

I have a section `Posts` that has an Entries-type field called `Authors` that can be linked to one or more entries in section called `People`. To make a filter for my posts index, I need to fetch all the `People` entries that have been linked to any post via the Authors field, but I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to query for all post entries and then query for the authors that are related to a post. You can use the `ids()` method to get just the author’s element IDs, which is a lot quicker than `find()`.

```
{% set allPostIds = craft.entries({
    section: 'posts',
    limit: null,
}).ids() %}

{% set people = craft.entries({
    section: 'people',
    relatedTo: {
        sourceElement: allPostIds,
        field: 'people',
    },
}) %}
```

Comment: Great, but to confuse matters I have two People entry fields: Authors and People - I only want to match authors... any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Sure, I just updated the answer.